# CORS not working with JQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-headers, cors

I have some JQuery code that logs a user into the system by connecting to my api, which is on a subdomain - api.foo.com

My JQuery code is:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
crossDomain: true,
url: "http://api.foo.com",
data: {json:"true",com:"login",username:$('#LoginUsername').val(),password:$('#LoginPassword').val()},
dataType: "json",
success: function(Data) {
    console.log("Request sent and data received");
    console.log(Data);
}
});
```

The issue is that in the console, I get the error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.foo.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://foo.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

I know for a fact that I have set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to * in my php code - `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` and I have checked in on google chrome (See screenshot below).

I originally opened a question about this issue but realised I had misspelled the header, whereas this time that is not the case.

The screenshot below is of the headers I receive when I connect to api.foo.com directly.

[image: Screenshot of the headers response]

Comment: Do you have the access allow origin set on api.foo.com?

Comment: @PanamaJack the headers screenshot is of the headers recieved when connecting to api.foo.com

Comment: What are your request headers?

Comment: Specifically are your setting any custom headers?